# Horizontally center wide image in Bearmer class

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, wide-image

Consider the document below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Sample title}
\author{Coyote}
\institute{Acme}
\date{2020}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}

  \begin{figure}[ht]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height=6.5cm]{United_Nations}
  \end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Using [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/United_Nations_Members.svg/940px-United_Nations_Members.svg.png) from Wikipaedia it produces the following:

[image]

There is plenty of space in the frame to portrait the image in its entirety, but since it is not horizontally centered it is truncated. Beyond `\centering`, I also tried with `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` but the effect is the same. I was neither successful with `\hspace`.

How can an image be horizontally centered in this setting? I am looking for a formulation that is independent of the size of this particular image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the picture in your `figure` into a `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{...}`. This centers the picture to the normal text width even if it is wider than that. You can also make the image aligned with the left and right textmargin using `[l]` and `[r]`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Sample title}
\author{Coyote}
\institute{Acme}
\date{2020}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=6.5cm]{United_Nations}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The figure environment is not very useful because its floating function is disabled in beamer.

Comment: The floating mechanism of `figure` is disabled when used in the `beamer` documentclass.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.StackExchange.